# ShortestPath doesn't find any path without max hops limit

Tags: neo4j

In my graph there is a path between vertices 5 and 36 but when I run query:

`match (n {Id:5}), (m {Id:36}), p=shortestPath(n-[*]->m) return length(p);`

I get 0 rows returned. I get results though when I add maximum hops limit to a path:

`match (n {Id:5}), (m {Id:36}), p=shortestPath(n-[*..100]->m) return length(p);`

Can someone explain to me why query without max hops limit doesn't work?

Comment: This is strange, you do not have to add maximum hops to limit the path. What happens if you try this: `match (n {Id:5}), (m {Id:36}), p=shortestPath(n-[*]-m) return length(p)` i.e to skip the directional relationship in the `shortestPath` query?

Comment: Returned 0 rows. According to neo4j's docs it should work, but it don't.

Comment: that is odd, i created 1000 nodes each with two random connections and ran both your queries and got responses. what version are you running with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this same problem, and I found out that if you don't inform the maximum hops, the shortestPath will limit the **maximum hops** to **15**. I'm using neo4j 2.2.1