# Linked list query takes too long

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have build a linked list model using `neo4j`. Here there is a representation:

[image: Linked list of events]

A user has a list of `Events` and each one has two attributes: `date` and `done`. Given a particular time, I would like to set all previous events' `done` attribute to `true`.

My current query is this one:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: {myId} })-[rel:PREV*]->(event:Event {done:false}) 
WHERE event.date <= {eventTime}
SET event.done = true;
```

This query takes 12 sec when the list has 500 events and I would like to make it faster. One possibility would be to stop the query once it finds an event which is already done, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: "takes too  long when the list is really big" and "make it faster" are fairly meaningless here, as we have no idea what "really big" means: Hundreds? Thousands? How long is the query taking? How long do you expect it to take?

Comment: @DavidMakogon For example, it takes 12 seconds to perform the query if the list has 500 events. It seams too much because the majority of the events are done (less than 10 have done=true).

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `shortestPath`?

Comment: @NicoleWhite - Unless I completely misunderstand the OP's question, ShortestPath is not going to solve the problem. The intent appears to deal with a bulk number of nodes where `done = false` and set them to `true`. `ShortestPath` would serve only to find the most recent not-done event, which doesn't appear to be needed.

Comment: The shortest path function would find the shortest path to each Event node where done=false, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shortestPath` for this and it will be much faster. In general,  you should never use `[:REL_TYPE*]` because it does an exhaustive search for *every* path of *any* length between the nodes.

I created your data:

```
CREATE (:User {id:1})-[:PREV]->(:Event {id:1, date:1450806880004, done:false})-[:PREV]->(:Event {id:2, date:1450806880003, done:false})-[:PREV]->(:Event {id:3, date:1450806880002, done:true})-[:PREV]->(:Event {id:4, date:1450806880002, done:true});
```

Then, the following query will find all previous Event nodes in a particular User's linked list where done=false and the date is less than or equal to, say, 1450806880005.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((u:User)-[:PREV*]->(e:Event))
WHERE u.id = 1 AND 
      e.done = FALSE AND 
      e.date <= 1450806880005
RETURN p;
```

This yields:

```
p
[(6:User {id:1}), (6)-[6:PREV]->(7), (7:Event {date:1450806880004, done:false, id:1})]
[(6:User {id:1}), (6)-[6:PREV]->(7), (7:Event {date:1450806880004, done:false, id:1}), (7)-[7:PREV]->(8), (8:Event {date:1450806880003, done:false, id:2})]
```

So you can see it's returning two paths, one that terminates at Event with id=1 and another that terminates at Event with id=2.

Then you can do something like this:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((u:User)-[:PREV*]->(e:Event))
WHERE u.id = 1 AND e.done = FALSE AND e.date <= 1450806880005
FOREACH (event IN TAIL(NODES(p)) | SET event.done = TRUE)
RETURN p;
```

I'm using TAIL here because it grabs all the nodes except for the first one (since we don't want to update this property for the User node). Now all of the done properties have been updated on the Event nodes:

```
p
[(6:User {id:1}), (6)-[6:PREV]->(7), (7:Event {date:1450806880004, done:true, id:1})]
[(6:User {id:1}), (6)-[6:PREV]->(7), (7:Event {date:1450806880004, done:true, id:1}), (7)-[7:PREV]->(8), (8:Event {date:1450806880003, done:true, id:2})]
```

EDIT: And don't forget the super fun bug where the `shortestPath` function silently sets the maximum hop limit to 15 in Neo4j < 2.3.0. See

[ShortestPath doesn't find any path without max hops limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28053134/2848578)

[Find all events between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685803/2848578)

So if you're on Neo4j < 2.3.0, you'll want to do:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((u:User)-[:PREV*..1000000000]->(e:Event))
WHERE u.id = 1 AND e.done = FALSE AND e.date <= 1450806880005
FOREACH (event IN TAIL(NODES(p)) | SET event.done = TRUE)
RETURN p;
```

Comment: I have tested your query in different lists but it always returns (and changes) the first 15 Events.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you on? I believe that was fixed in Neo4j 2.3.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32686764/2848578 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162759/2848578. The solution is to set an arbitrarily high maximum within the shortestPath function, something like `[PREV*..1000000000]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is fairly vague with performance issues and targets, but one critical thing for performance is creating an index on properties you are examining. In your case, that would mean creating an index on both the `done` property and the `date` property:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Event(done)
CREATE INDEX ON :Event(date)
```

Additionally, your query retrieves *all* events in the entire history of a user, as seen in:

`-[rel:PREV*]->`

You could cap the depth, such as

`-[rel:PREV*..20]->`

to prevent complete traversal. That might not give you the outcome you're looking for, but it would prevent long-running queries if you have an extreme number of nodes in your linked list (you haven't specified how large that list could get, so I have no idea if this will actually help).